# SonarQube error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, aura

So when I run SonarQube I get this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." for all Aura JS Controllers and helpers.

Aura JS sample code:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {....}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We faced this issue.

You need to disable some `js` rules, like this one, as this is not built for Aura framework.

Comment: ok, is there any reference document that aura does not support this rule or something?

Comment: No, but sonar js rules are not built for all framework written in JS, you wont find this in any documentation. The reason is because `({})` is an expression and its expecting a name for that expression which you cannot give in Aura.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing that out, will try the rule disable approach.